# Boost::Archive causing weird linker error

Tags: c++, linker-errors, boost-serialization

Does anyone have a clue why those two lines would cause that linker error?

```
std::ifstream ifs("filename.file");
boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchv( ifs );
```

> Error   8       fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file `'F:\dev\project\build\win32-unit\tests\Debug\framework_core_tests.lib'`    `ramework_core_tests`    `framework_core_tests`

The same happens with any Boost::Archive type.

Its trying to link against a library of the same name as my executable for some reason when that project doesn't nor never existed and is not defined as a library to link against in my project files.

Comment: The compiler im using is VC++ 9

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add a reference to a lib that contains that functions?

Comment: Please read the thread thoroughly again. This library it is trying to link against never had existed, nor am I missing any library references. 

That's the odd part about this linker error, I am linking against libboost-serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled this library with core tests.